Open MS Access database without COM
I need to open MS Access database in .net8 app, which uses AOT compilation.
AOT compilation has some limitations, like Windows: No built-in COM.
Is there any way to read MS Access in such AOT app except to convert it to some other format?
[EDIT]
My usual reader throws this exception:

at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid
clsid, String server, Boolean throwOnError)    at
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.CreateInstanceDataLinks()
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.GetObjectPool()
Message: Built-in COM has been disabled via a feature switch. See
https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink/com for more information.


"No built-in COM" doesn't mean you can't use COM with AOT, it means you must disable built-in marshaling and use the newer ComWrapper tooling (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/tutorial-comwrappers) and with .NET8 it means you can (read: should) use the "Source generation for ComWrappers" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/comwrappers-source-generation). What's exactly your question about "opening MS Access database"?

Good comment, I have attached more details and I guess I will have to read your articles about this topic.

It won't work because current System.Data.OleDb package is not AOT (or trimming for that matter, since AOT requires trimming compatibility) friendly. I'm not sure if Microsoft has plans for this one to be ported (they're working on AOT support for bigger projects such as Winforms). You can get System.Data.OleDb's source and port it yourself, it's quite feasable, although a bit of work.
